# cmdstanR: extracting draws from stan model fit

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I am trying to extract draws from a stan model.  The stan file is as follows:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  int<lower=0, upper=1> obs_data[N];
}

parameters {
  real<lower=0, upper=1> lambda;
}

model {
  target += uniform_lpdf(lambda | 0,1);
  for (n in 1:N) {
    target += bernoulli_logit_lpmf(obs_data[n] | lambda);
  }
}
```

I am using cmdstanR to compile and sample from the model.

```
dl <- list(N = 10, obs_data = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1))

mod <- cmdstan_model("model.stan") // file pasted above
fit <- mod$sample(data, data = dl, num_chains = 4, num_cores = 4)
```

The resulting fit objects is as follows:

```
> fit$draws()
, , variable = lambda

         chain
iteration           1          2           3          4
     1    0.419819000 0.85642500 0.319154000 0.73338700
     2    0.807612000 0.78189500 0.737518000 0.73338700
     3    0.609196000 0.65826000 0.601450000 0.37992200
     4    0.390631000 0.84544000 0.601450000 0.17992400
```

From the fit object, which is a R6 object, I want to get only the draw variable values.  how do I do that?

Based on a followup comment, I am adding additional information on the internal structure of the R6 object for greater clarity:

```
> str(fit$draws())
 'draws_array' num [1:1000, 1:4, 1:2] 0.42 0.808 0.609 0.391 0.391 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ iteration: chr [1:1000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ chain    : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  ..$ variable : chr [1:2] "lambda" "lp__"
```

Comment: What is the output of `str(fit$draws())`?

Comment: Do you mean you want `fit$draws()[, , 1]`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I get the following for str(fit$draws()):
 'draws_array' num [1:1000, 1:4, 1:2] 0.42 0.808 0.609 0.391 0.391 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ iteration: chr [1:1000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ chain    : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  ..$ variable : chr [1:2] "lambda" "lp__"

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, I am looking to extract the (draws) values of the parameter "lambda" from the R6 fit object.

Comment: And `fit$draws()[, , 1]` does not give what you want ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, thanks for the suggestion.  I was able to get it with: fit$draws()[, , 1] %>% as.tibble()

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the prompts / suggestions from @StéphaneLaurent and @RomanLuštrik, I was able to get to what I wanted.  I was looking to draws values of the sampling result from stan.

Based on the suggestions from @RomanLuštrik,

str(fit$draws()), gives the map to the different indices; the first being the "iteration", then the "chain" and finally the "variable".

Since I was looking to extract draws for the "lambda" parameter (the "variable"); I could access it through

```
fit$draws()[,,1].
```

To draw the samples from the 1 and 3rd chains, and the first 25 samples for the parameter "lambda", I need to use

```
fit$draws()[1:25,c(1,3),1]
```